# Memory leak in Windows Forms ComboBox since .Net Framework 4.8

Tags: .net, winforms, memory-leaks, combobox

We switched from .NET Framework 4.6 to 4.8 a few weeks ago. Since that time, we have a memory leak that is caused by the .NET Framework itself.

.NET Framework 4.8 uses Level 3 of accessibility features. In case of the win forms combobox, this means that the `System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.AccessibilityObject` property contains an object of a internal subclass `System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.ComboBoxUiaProvider` that has internal property `ItemAccesssibleObjects`, which is a dictionary that contains all items that were added to this combobox, ever.

So even if you clear the items in the combobox, this internal dictionary still has a reference to the item. So all items that ever were added to the combobox get cumulated... This is a memory leak.

I have a [full fledged sample on GitHub](https://github.com/huber/ComboBoxMemoryLeakSample) which shows the effect.

If the project is changed back to .NET Framework 4.6, the memory leak does not exist since another subclass of `System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.AccessibilityObject` will be used.

I guess I can "solve" this problem by deactivating the Level 3 Accessibility Features of .NET Framework 4.8, but this is a too bad solution in my opinion.

Sure, I guess I can use reflection to solve this (remove the item from the internal dictionary), but I also don't like this option since this are internals and may change in future...

Does anyone knows this problem / is there already a good solution available?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be :

- to override the `ComboBox` class with your own : let's say `OwnComboBox`.
- to override the function `CreateAccessibilityInstance()` and keep in the overridden class the reference to the `ComboBoxUiaProvider` (`AccessibleObject`) created by the base function (be carreful, it can be something else than `ComboBoxUiaProvider`).
- to override the function `Dispose(bool disposing)` and clean manually the internal dictionary.

Link that could help : [ComboBox code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ComboBox.cs,81b9e6940fa637bf,references).

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be :

- to to override the ComboBox class with your own : let's say `OwnComboBox`.
- to override the function `Dispose(bool disposing)` and perform this call : `this.WndProc(NativeMethods.WM_NCDESTROY)`.

Link that could help : [ComboBox code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ComboBox.cs,3842).

Comment: I do not have the possibility to subclass combobox since the combobox control is generated from a ribbon bar control that does not allow this level of control.

Comment: Maybe you can subclass the ribbon bar too to override the function that returns the combobox ?

Answer (score 0):

We have a very similar problem. UserObjects and GDIObjects are leaking after upgrading from .net 4.6 to 4.8. It is visible only when we run memory leak tests via automation tools. When clicking manually or if we modified internal code to just invoke button click handlers which go through forms and close them there was no memory leak.

Adding this to app.config

```
<runtime>
    <AppContextSwitchOverrides value="Switch.UseLegacyAccessibilityFeatures=false;Switch.UseLegacyAccessibilityFeatures.2=false;Switch.UseLegacyAccessibilityFeatures.3=true"/>
</runtime>
```

solved it but then we realized that we cannot run our app in debug mode or there are some strange errors.

We found out that if all comboboxes are removed from the view then there is no memory leak. So the problem is 100% in Combobox. We tried both answers from Bioukh and the one with Dispose worked... but later I checked and there was no need to override ComboBox. The problem we faced was caused by not Disposing ComboBoxes when removing them dynamically from the view.

Our problem was that we we reuse the view. We remove ComboBoxes from the view and then we add new ones without disposing the old ones. Apparently GC doesn't dispose them automatically or there is something holding on to them (I tried hard but didn't find anything).

The fix was - before removing them we make a copy of the list, remove them from the view and then dispose each item on the list. The memory leak is gone now.
Here's a [link to documentation about removing controls from a collection programmatically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-add-to-or-remove-from-a-collection-of-controls-at-run-time?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#:%7E:text=To%20remove%20controls%20from%20a%20collection%20programmatically&text=In%20Visual%20Basic%2C%20use%20the,resources%20used%20by%20the%20control)